# Schengen visa query for my wife who is Nigerian but has leave to remain in UK

Tags: visas, schengen

My wife (Nigerian) has leave to remain in UK for 2 years. We applied for a Schengen visa to go to Spain for one-month holiday which we did then came back to UK. She still has 4 months before it expires (it was a 6 month visa). **Can we go directly to any other Schengen country now for another holiday, or do we have to go via Spain as they issued the visa?** We would like to go to visit friends in Belgium.

Comment: Assuming it's a multiple entry Schengen visa, this sounds a lot like another question asked a few days ago: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/schengen-visa-multiple-entry

Comment: (+1 because it's a good question; voting to close because it's likely a duplicate.)

Comment: I think this question should not be closed. Halabi's answer for instancce correctly clarifies the situation.

Answer (score 5):

If the visa is multi-entry visa then the answer is **yes, she can go to any other country within the Schengen area.**

If the visa is a single entry visa, then **no, She can not go. She has to apply for a new visa.**