# Having a Multiple entry Schengen Visa from Germany, Can I make a trip to France?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, germany

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a multiple-entry Schengen visa allow visiting other Schengen countries later, without going via the issuing country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late)

I live in UK, and have obtained a 3 month valid Multiple Entry Schengen Visa from German Embassy. The Visa says maximum stay of 30 days during the 3 month validity. I made my first trip to Germany-Spain (1 week duration). Now, **can I visit other Schengen countries (France / Czech Republic) without visiting Germany** (and not exceeding the 30 day maximum stay period of course)?

I am not able to find a direct answer to this question on the embassy page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel SE! Have a look at this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late I'm not 100% sure, but looks like it's essentially the same as what you asked.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is **yes**, with your multiple-entry visa you can visit other Schengen countries directly, without visiting Germany.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jonik. The other post answers my question. Now I am more confident of booking my tickets! Thanks again.