# I am from South Africa, visiting the UK and would like to apply for a multiple entry Schengen visa to visit Paris. Is that possible?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, south-african-citizens

And will it possible to use the Schengen visa to visit Italy etc?

Comment: Is SA referring to South Africa, Argentina, or maybe even Sachsen-Altenburg?

Comment: Once you have a Schengen visa, you can go to all Schengen members.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late/9650#9650

Comment: Where will you apply? in _SA_ or UK?

Comment: @Andra - yes, but the UK is not in the Schengen area.

Comment: @MarkMayo I was referring to  Italian part of the question. You can travel to Italy from Paris, once you obtained a Schengen visa

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Yes, that's accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes.

I have several friends from South Africa who have either moved to the UK, or who have been just visiting the UK.

They regularly then apply for Schengen visas - multiple entry, especially if they're doing a big trip - like one that includes darting off to Egypt or similar.  A multi-entry Schengen visa certainly exists, and you can certainly apply for it from the UK, even if not a British Citizen.

Finally, I believe you specify on the application where you want to go, so mentioning Italy would make that easy, but regardless, you can travel anywhere within the Schengen area once you're inside - there are no borders.

Comment: Just to add, yes you can apply for a visa within the UK and I have seen a lot of people doing that. But you have to have a valid visa within the UK more than 3 months or you need to show that you're intended to go home by showing a flight to your home country.