# Schengen visa for Amsterdam and Paris

Tags: visas, schengen, france, schengen-visas, netherlands

I am flying from Johannesburg to Paris. I want to spend a couple of days there. Then I am going to Amsterdam with the train to spend a couple of days there. I am flying back from Amsterdam to Johannesburg.

I did apply for my Netherland visa (Schengen visa) - do I need to apply for another visa for Paris as well?

Comment: **No**. France and Netherlands are both in Schengen so the one visa covers both. Be aware that you can only stay **90 days** in Schengen out of any **180 day** period.

Answer (score 5):

No you do not need another visa. Schengen visa gives you access to all Schengen area so you are free to move within Schengen area as long as it is valid and you follow the [90/180](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) rule [regardless of the issuance state and the entry state](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-me-schengen-visa). In other words think of Schengen area as a big country and think of member states as cities of that big country, you are granted access to that big country so visiting cities within that big country is granted by default.