# Can I travel on back-to-back Schengen visas without leaving and reentering the area?

Tags: visas, schengen

I currently have a valid multiple entry Schengen visa that expires on Feb 10th (issued by the Spanish consulate). I need to visit the Czech Republic from Feb 9th to Feb 15th. For this, I am getting a visa starting Feb 11th from the Czech consulate as I was advised that I cannot have two simultaneous visas.

Is it possible for me to enter Czech republic on the current visa on Feb 9th, and stay past its expiry up to Feb 15th using the new visa *without* leaving the Czech Republic? Will there be any likely problem either while entering or exiting Schengen zone (I am entering Schengen in Frankfurt)?

Comment: You are aware of the 90/180 rule, correct?

Comment: Lates information from the German Consulate regarding similar situation:  They require direct contact from the Visa Holder and scanned copy of the Visas.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, yes -- i am well within the 90 day limit.

Comment: @Karlson, I have applied in person to the czech republic consulate -- they have my passport with the old visa.

Comment: @SRT so did you ask them this question?

Comment: Just an update -- I was able to travel without any issues. I used the old visa to enter, and exited after the old one had expired but while the new one was valid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible as this particular scenario is even offered as an example in the *[Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)*

> ***Example:*** A Moroccan lawyer representing a gender equality NGO who frequently 
>   participates in meetings in various Member States holds a multiple-entry-visa which expires 
>   on 31.5. She applies for a new visa on 15.4.
>
> If a new visa is issued, it should be valid from 1.6. and in such a case the visa holder would be entitled to enter the territory of the Member States on the basis of the first visa that will expire during the stay and leave on the basis of the new visa.