# I have a valid Schengen visa issued for 35 days. How should I proceed if I need to stay for a longer time?

Tags: visas, schengen

So my problem is that I have a Schengen Visa delivered by the Spanish Embassy, valid from August 01st 2014 to September 19th with a 35 days stay duration with one entry. I'm gonna be in Spain from August 3rd until September 6th, which is the limit of my 35 days, and then I want to go to Germany to stay there for some time.

Can I apply for a Schengen visa from German Embassy from 6th or 7th of September?

If yes, will I have to leave the Schengen space and return to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they would issue a new overlapping visa. Since it's all one trip, you should in principle have applied to one consulate with documentation covering the stay in both countries.

Since you already have that visa, I am not sure what your options are now. One possibility could be to have Spanish visa revoked and start a new application but that sounds like a lot of hassle.

If you do get a new visa, traveling on two visas is not a problem and you wouldn't need to leave the area, see [Traveling on back-to-back Schengen visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/traveling-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. My problem is that I applied for the spanish embassy with documentation covering my stay in both coutries but they considered only the documents concerning my stay in spain. Of course, they don't listen to complains..