# If I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa and need to stay for 2 days past its validity, will my existing visa be extended or will I get a new one?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-extensions

I have a type C multiple entry visa, valid for a year until 06/08 but I was thinking to start my trip before it expires and end around 07/08 or 08/08. I then want to go to Schengen zone again, so my question is whether I can apply now  and have a new Schengen visa perhaps for another year starting from 07/08 (right after my current one expires).

Or are they likely to just extend it for a day? Before I had 3, 6 and now 12 month visa. The point for me is to get it for another year, otherwise it is not worth it. I read about needing to cancel existing visa before you can get new one. I'm going to get it from the same embassy as before so I believe they can cancel it as its their own visa and then give me new visa for this trip and beyond?  Does anyone know anything about that?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, can i just ask whether it matters whether i will need it for 1 or 2 extra days? Its probably a nuisance but i just want to make sure, as ideally i would like to travel on 07/08 (it expires on 06/08) but i can get a ticket for 08/08 if required, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Getting a new visa that starts right after the previous one expired is perfectly possible. There is nothing in the regulation preventing it and it's actually among the “best practices” recommended by the EU Commission for multiple-entry visas. It's also fine to enter the Schengen area on one visa and leave on another one, as long as there is no gap between them, see [Traveling on back-to-back Schengen visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/traveling-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas)

My readings of the rules is that yours is not a situation in which they would typically extend a visa but I am not completely sure about that. A consulate can also of course cancel a visa it issued and replace it with another one but, unless it's to correct a mistake they have made, they will probably require that you submit a new application and pay the fee so they might just as well issue a separate visa.

Beyond that, whether you will actually get a long multiple-entry visa might depend on many details (your profile, past travels to the Schengen area, location, consulate/destination, the documentation you submit/need to travel).

Also, two notes about the procedure:

- You can always join a letter (keep it short and business-like) to your application to explain your situation and help the consulate understand your needs.
- I think that if a consulate decides they cannot issue a visa for a technical reason like that, they should reject the application quickly, return the documents and refund the fee. It would not count as a formal refusal with all the associated consequences.