Two Schengen visa in sequence (back to back visa)
I have two Schengen visa issued by the Netherlands Consulate. The first one expires on July 26th 2024, the second one starts from July 27th 2024 will last for a year (till July 2025). I’m going to Netherlands on July 20th and leaving on August 2nd. Would this cause any issue when entering Netherlands?

This is normal. You have a visa(s) to enter and remain for your expected duration of your visit. See How long before can I apply for new schengen visa before it expires?

@MarkJohnson The other question isn't a duplicate, didn't have an answer addressing the question, and is closed anyway. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/can-i-travel-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas-without-leaving-and-reentering-the-a is the actual duplicate.
