Schengen Visa Travel Inquiry
I have a Schengen visa from Switzerland valid from 13th Dec 23 to 13th Dec 24 (visa 1) I got another Schengen visa from Vrance validity: 14th Dec'24 to 13th Dec 27 (visa 2)
Can I travel to schengen region on 8th Dec (based on visa 1) and come back on 5th jan (based on visa 2) as I have continuous coverage? Or I will be able to start my trip only after 14th Dec i.e. visa 2 validity?

Yes this is completely fine, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/can-i-travel-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas-without-leaving-and-reentering-the-a

You have the required visa to enter and remain in the Schengen Area from the 2024-12-08 until the 2025-01-05 (29 days).
This assumes that the duration given in the visa is 29 or more. If the duration field is empty (or ---), then up 90 days in any 180 day period is allowed.
It is normal that Schengen visas do not overlap (i.e. the second visa starts the day after the first ends).

A 3-year visa ought to be valid for stays up to 90 days in any 180-day period.

Thanks Mark - Duration of stay on both visas is mentioned as 90D so I should be ok to travel right?
As both visas are MULTIPLE entry visas, I am assuming it means 90days of stay in 180 days duration in the visa validity period, not 90 days for whole validity of visa (i.e. 90 days in 3 years).
