# I have two Schengen visas with adjoining dates, is it OK to travel?

Tags: schengen

I have two Schengen visas, both multiple-entry, both issues by the Netherlands embassy. One expires on the 30th of September and the other start October 1st. I want to be in Paris from 30th Oct-2Oct. Is it OK to travel?

Comment: I don't understand the dates but it's perfectly fine to enter on one visa and leave on the other, provided you fulfill all other relevant conditions, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23350/traveling-on-back-to-back-schengen-visas and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22757/visiting-greece-with-back-to-back-schengen-visas-one-from-germany-other-from-i

Answer (score 2):

Your first Schengen will expire at 23:59 on 30 Sept.  Your second will begin at 24:00 on 1 Oct.  They are the same instant and you are legal throughout.  You can use the Schengen calculator to determine if 1 Oct counts as a day of leave or as an 'arrival' day and how that will affect your overall spent leave in the Schengen zone.  But for your question:  yes, you are ok.

Comment: simple correction: Your second will begin at 00:00 on 1 Oct.