# Single trip to conferences in two Schengen countries with one visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, conferences

I am Ukrainian and currently considering if trying to stack attending two professional conferences under one visa is great optimization or crazy talk. :)

Conferences will be on consecutive weekends in:

- Switzerland, May 3-4
- Netherlands, May 10-11

I can get business invitations for both, no issues there. I have previously been to Netherlands (also for a conference with short stay visa), but not Switzerland.

To be clear I am considering about going from Switzerland to Netherlands directly (essentially having some touristy time), not coming back to Ukraine in the middle and re-entering for Netherlands.

1. Would this look like relatively "sane" application for visa?
2. If I plan to stay more days in Netherlands and apply for visa in its embassy, would I have any issues entering and spending initial days in Switzerland?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued me Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-me-schengen-visa)

Comment: As far as the sanity goes why would you be concerned?

Comment: For the record I've read that one and get that entry and main stay can be different countries. In my case this is more nuanced if it would be relatively more reliable to _make_ them separate (better chances with repeat application to NL) or _make_ them same (more days in and visa to CH).

Comment: @Karlson I have been denied US visa to event I wanted to go badly in the past, so I am being very sensitive/nervous about visa issues. :\ I want to build good travel history and not risk visa denials by making applications unlikely to succeed.

Comment: US denies a lot if not moat applications from Ukraine.  At least the first time around.  You needed a letter of invitation from a reputable organization to swing it.  Started when Yanyk came to power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can only offer opinions on this, but your situation sounds **perfectly sensible** to me, especially since you have previously been granted a Schengen visa and don't even need a multiple-entry visa.  It doesn't really matter if the previous visa was granted by the Netherlands or Switzerland, because it's all in the same database now.

Just make sure you get invitations to both conferences, proof of funds to cover the entire period, travel insurance and fulfill [the rest of the standard Schengen requirements](http://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/south_africa/documents/schengen_visa_requirments_en.pdf).

And as stated in the answers to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-me-schengen-visa), you do not need to enter via the country that granted you the visa.

Comment: Thank you, it's good piece of information that database is shared. I also just came back from conference in Norway so I currently have two completed schengen visas in passport.