# Indian National transiting through Helsinki

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens

I am travelling to Krakow, Poland and have a stopover at Helsinki from 3.55pm one day to 9.55 am the next day. Do I need a transit visa and if so, how do I get it?

Comment: Not a dupe of that question for me because here the destination is Schengen not merely a layover. So the Schengen visa needed for the destination will do as OP enters Schengen in Helsinki.

Comment: I think this is the better duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13362/43483

Comment: I agree with @Jan on which is the correct duplicate; there is no need for a transit visa _in addition to the Schengen visa_ that the OP has. Or at least, _needs_. Without a Schengen visa, she won't be allowed onto the initial flight into Helsinki and transit is irrelevant. The OP should also note that she should be able to leave the airport terminal and get a decent night's sleep at a hotel with the Schengen visa she already has (should have). She does not need to remain airside.

Answer (score 2):

Poland and Finland are both part of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), so if you have a visa to enter Poland, it should permit you access to Finland as well.