# Getting Schengen visa from a European country without stepping foot into it?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have an upcoming travel for a conference in country A. But their consulate is pretty busy and I would like to get my visa sooner.

Can I go to the consulate of a different country B which doesn't need appointment for visa applications and get my visa from there? I can schedule to be in A for 5 days and in B for 7 days.

What if I change my plans later not to visit country B at all and go a country C or just stay in A the whole time? Will there be issues when entering or exiting Schengen states?

Comment: I only just noticed your edit. You should move it to an answer and accept that.

Comment: When you wrote "even though you spend more time in A", was that a typo, and you really meant "even though you spend more time in B"?

Comment: @Ryan That's right. Fixed. I actually just made it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I called consulate of country B and talked with the visa officer. He told me since you are visiting country A for a conference that is your main destination even though you spend more time in B. He said the rules say: 1. main destination 2. if no, longest stay 3. if no, entrance. He told me that he is reluctant to issue me a visa and asked me to contact country A's consulate, if they don't take the application he will review it.

I called consulate of country A. First the operator told me to go to B then after telling her that I am going to A for business (conference), she told me that I should apply at theirs (A).

Looks like the key thing here is the conference not where I spend most of my time.

Answer (score 5):

There are already many questions touching upon the subject (although perhaps no exact duplicate):

- [Use of unused Schengen visa to travel to Switzerland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30679/use-of-unused-schengen-visa-to-travel-to-switzerland?lq=1)
- [What's the quickest Schengen consulate to issue a visa in London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26485/whats-the-quickest-schengen-consulate-to-issue-a-visa-in-london)
- [Can I travel to Spain using a Greek Schengen visa even if I don't want to stay in Greece at all?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27672/can-i-travel-to-spain-using-a-greek-schengen-visa-even-if-i-dont-want-to-stay-i?lq=1)
- [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point)
- [Schengen visa requirements and "validation"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/schengen-visa-requirements-and-validation)

In a nutshell: going to different countries or changing plans with a multiple-entry visa valid for more than six months is not a problem at all. Using a single-entry visa for an entirely different purpose is a bit more tricky and showing up somewhere completely unexpected with no credible story can create problems. In your scenario, since you already know you don't really want to go to country B, you would in fact be committing fraud.

Incidentally, submitting a conference invitation/registration in country A *could* suggest that your real destination is country A and your random trip to country B was just added to skirt the regulations. In practice, it might be difficult for the consulate or the border guards to notice it and you might therefore be OK but it is certainly a valid reason to deny or annul the visa.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to apply for your Schengen Visa at the consulate/embassy of the country in which you are spending the bulk of your time.  Or if none are taking the majority of your time, then you are supposed to apply to the first country to be entered.

Your itinerary of 5 and 7 days is probably in the gray area between the two.  Best bet contact Embassy B and ask if you can apply.

Comment: My actual question was what if I get visa from B and not visit B at all or shorten my stay in B.

Comment: I don't think that shortening your stay in B will have an effect on your trip, but skipping B all together might.  There was a group to Thai tourists that got their visa from one country for a multi-country tour, then never visited the issuing country.  They had a run in with immigration upon departure, but were eventually allowed out. The tour operator was fined though, but not the travelers.

Comment: As @MohammadMoghimi notes in his edited question, the rule is in fact that you must apply with the country that is your main destination.  The amount of time spent in a country is an important factor in determining the main destination, but not the only factor.  If the purpose of the trip is purely tourism, there is unlikely to be any other factor, but in case of conferences or other particular reasons for visiting particular countries, the duration-of-stay criterion may become unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no issues. Once you have a Schengen Visa your itinerary can change. You will not be asked why you are not traveling to Country B. Even if they do, you can cite a change of plans and they won't care much.

Of course this only makes sense with a [Uniform 'C' visa](http://www.ecg.lv/en/actual.php?news_id=4).

Comment: what is a C visa?

Comment: A typical tourist/business visa is a C visa.