# I have a netherlands visa, can my port of entry be Madrid?

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas

I have a Netherlands visa. My plans have changed drastically. I would be staying most number of days in Spain. Can i have my POE in Madrid? Will it be a problem if neither my POE not my maximum number of days are not in the country from where i got my Schengen visa?

Comment: Note that your **main destination** for visa purposes is not necessarily the one where the largest number of days are spent. For example if you're going to a professional conference in the Netherlands and combining it with some vacationing in Spain, the Netherlands would still be your main destination.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be a problem, especially if you have single entry visa. If you enter Spain with single entry visa issued by Netherlands, you will likely be asked to confirm that Netherlands is either your main destination or the place of the longest stay. (See another answer to the [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/getting-schengen-visa-from-a-european-country-without-stepping-foot-into-it) and follow the links)