# Applying for a Schengen Visa without itinerary

Tags: schengen

I am currently residing in Ireland with work authorization permit. In the next few months I am planning for a trip to few schengen countries. I have not yet decided my itinerary. Is there any Schengen country embassy which can process a tourist Schengen visa for 90 days?

Comment: All countries in the Schengen area and all their consulates are supposed to apply the same rules. All of them can grant a visa for 90 days (that's the maximum stay under short-stay rules) but they should not do it if you do not intend to visit the country in question.

Comment: @Sandy Hi and welcome to Travel.SE. Your question is confusing because the title asks about applying for a Schengen visa without an itinerary while the body of the question just asks for an embassy.

Comment: The first question (in the title) is a possible duplicate of [What does “copy of itinerary” mean when applying for a Schengen visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/12870/108) and [Schengen visa requirements and “validation”](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6609/108)

Answer (score 1):

All countries in the Schengen area and all their consulates are supposed to follow the same rules. Some might be a bit stricter in their interpretation but all of them can grant a visa for 90 days (that's the maximum stay under short-stay rules) and they should not do it if you do not intend to visit the country in question. There is no such thing as an “open” application.

Consequently, you are not allowed to choose a consulate by convenience, you must first decide on your itinerary and then apply to the consulate of the country that will be your main destination. Of course, if you are completely flexible, you can still adjust your plans to target a specific country but that's certainly not officially encouraged.

See also [Getting Schengen visa from a European country without stepping foot into it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/getting-schengen-visa-from-a-european-country-without-stepping-foot-into-it) and [What's the quickest Schengen consulate to issue a visa in London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26485/whats-the-quickest-schengen-consulate-to-issue-a-visa-in-london)

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten Schengen visa many times, at last minute.

Which consulate can one apply to?

- Place of maximum time / main destination
- Place of entry to the Schenghen nations

So, you have to prove / show/ convince the consular officer in front of you of the above.

Now, what can be done? This is the hack I suggest:

Let's say there are 3 Schengen nations in my story: A (entry point), B (main destination), and C (previous schenghen travel done).

I was in a city that did not have a consulate for A and the consulate for B was super slow in visa processing.  I needed to get the visa in 1/2 days and knew that C were pretty efficient at visa processing.

So, I made a print-out of a hostel booking for destination C. At the consulate, I suggested that I would be spending maximum time there and not in A, and got the visa in a few hours.

Again, I was traveling for 4/5 weeks so anything was possible as my trip was open/ flexible :)

What helped more was I was working in the US at the time and was doing a 5 week stopover trip on the way back from Asia. The fact that I had US Visa and a previous Schengen visa (expired: from prev visit) showed that I was not an overstay risk (try to enter and illegally immigrate).

Bottom-line, you are in a good place, position and have enough time to figure out which consulate around you is the most FRIENDLY to your 90 day intent.

Once you have the visa, plans can always change.. :) After all it's a 90 day trip.

Comment: It would probably work in many cases but [it can also back-fire](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa/44262#44262). And changing your mind and adding some time here or there is one thing but deliberately mischaracterizing your intent from the start and not going to C at all is fraud, plain and simple, and would make you liable to see your visa annulled (and not merely revoked as in the previous example).

Comment: And how would one differentiate, whether you changed travel plans later or intended earlier on? 

I understand the implications, but primary concern of consulates and countries is preventing 'bad' characters and facilitating 'good' people. So they have to form regulations that we work with and around it sometimes. 

To make it fool proof based on your link.. keep the HOSTEL booking on, dont cancel. Its only 10/ 20 bucks :)

Comment: That's why I wrote that “it would probably work in many cases” and I suggested as much in my answer. But working “around” a regulation is fraud, and not simply a “hack”. Everyone can decide if they want to do it or not but using euphemisms kind of obscures the nature of your suggestion and what the regulations really are.

Comment: From the link you pointed out, what if the people actually changed from one hotel to another due to some issue/ double booking at original hotel? Or family decides to stay a nicer hotel / different location in the city? I wonder what must they do as per REGULATION then? Contact consulate and say we changed hotel?

Comment: You will see that I commented there that I thought the Czech authorities were overzealous in this case, based on my understanding of the the regulation. But it can still happen. Conversely, the fact you can get away with much more than that does not mean it's allowed or risk-free. That's all I am saying.

Comment: @Relaxed of course, since the OP has not yet decided on an itinerary, the OP could determine which consulate is the best one to apply to, and then construct an itinerary for which that country is in fact the main destination.  *That,* at least, would not be fraud.