# Must I specify where I will enter the Schengen area on the visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen

Should I mention in my application form that I am entering a different country first and later I will be staying longer in the country which Schengen visa will be issued to me?

Please help me before I submit my application forms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should indicate where you will first enter the Schengen area on the form, e.g. under “border of first entry or transit route” (that's field 32 on [some forms](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/IMG/pdf/visagb.pdf)) or “Member state of first entry” (field 23 on the last version of the harmonized form [described in the Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN)).

This need not be the country from which you are applying for a visa, which, as you already know, [should be your *main* destination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28937/which-consulate-should-issue-me-a-schengen-visa-if-i-transit-through-several-sch/28938#28938) (but not necessarily the *first* one) and would be entered in field 21 or 22 (“Member State(s) of destination”/“Main destination”).

No matter what's on the form itself, you can also [submit an itinerary](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/what-does-copy-of-itinerary-mean-when-applying-for-a-schengen-visa) in which you can explain your plan and list all the countries you intend to visit.