# Invitation letters for my Indian parents coming to the Netherlands

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, invitation-letters

I want to call my parents, who are from India, to stay for a short period here in Netherlands

1. Do I need to send an invitation letter? Is that a mandatory document?
2. Is it ok if I gave my written letter stating invitation and purpose of calling them here?

Comment: This looks to be two different questions - as per the Help Center I'd strongly advise you to split it into two, one for the letter, one for the break of journey

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you narrow down the questions?  It seems that you have several categories of them including required documentation for obtaining a visa and whether or not the first stop should be in the destination country.

Comment: Regarding transit in Zurich, the answer is that you only need a single visa, because all of the Schengen area counts as one country for this type of visa. See [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa) and many other [tag:schengen] [tag:visas] questions.

Answer (score 3):

The consulate will expect to see this form/letter, especially if you want to act as a sponsor (which means that your parents would not need to show as much money as is usual for Schengen visas). Your parents also have to explain where they intend to stay and if they are staying with you, they will need this invitation to prove it.

In the Netherlands, you have to use a form called *[Bewijs van garantstelling en/of particuliere logiesverstrekking](https://ind.nl/EN/documents/1310.pdf)*. After filling it in, you need to go to the town administration (*gemeente*) to legalize your signature (you have to pay for that) and only then send it to your parents so that they can join it to their visa application. If you are a sponsor, they will also need some proof of *your* income (tax return or salary slips).