# Schengen Visa: Itinerary change after visa issued

Tags: visas, schengen, itineraries

I am an Indian passport holder got my schengen Business visa approved from Belgian consulate. At the time of applying visa, i have produced my travel itenary as, Norway (1N) --> Belgium (14N)

now due to some reason I have to reschedule it and will be like:
Norway: 1N
Finland: 2N
Sweden: 4N
Belgium: 8N

Can somebody guide me if this is OK? or do i have to follow some procedure?

Comment: What are your visa's validity/maximum stay limitations?

Answer (score 5):

For a detailed discussion of what is or isn't allowed, you can refer to [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782) or [Can I change my route and hotel reservation after getting a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa) and all the linked questions.

In your case, if your visa has enough validity (i.e. it must be valid for the whole period you would be in the Schengen area and authorise at least 15 days of stay, ideally a few more) and the purpose of the trip is still the same, it should not be problem. Belgium is still your main destination and you will still enter and leave through the same countries so no reason the change should be an issue either during the trip or afterwards.

If your visa cannot cover the whole journey (i.e. it does not allow 15 days of stay or it would expire before the end of your trip), then you need another one. There is no simple established procedure to get an extension, you will need to get in touch with the consulate, possibly start a new application from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this without any procedure. once you got Schengen visa,you can change your itinerary.

but make sure that you should stay minimum one night in that country from which you have got visa. according to your question, you can change your plan and travel another Schengen countries and stay some period. but make sure that you need to show minimum one night in Belgium as you have obtain visa through their embassy.