# Changing flights after having been granted a Schengen-Visa

Tags: visas, schengen

My girlfriend is currently a resident outside of the Schengen area while I'm a Swedish resident. She applied for a visitors visa with my invitation and was swiftly granted it.

However, we have later found a better flight than the reservation we used when applying for the visa. All the dates are exactly the same, but it is cheaper. The big difference is though that the original flight had a connection outside the Schengen zone while the new one has it inside, in Helsinki. The final destination airport is still the same (Arlanda) and she won't be staying in Helsinki, just getting on another plane there.

1. My understanding is that as Helsinki is the first Schengen airport she lands at she will have to pass through immigration there and not in Arlanda, correct?
2. Will she experience any trouble getting in or on the plants due to this change?

Comment: There are many other questions on itinerary changes after getting a Schengen visa: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49461/change-of-plans-in-schengen-visa, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45669/schengen-visa-itinerary-change-after-visa-issued

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45752/change-in-itinerary-after-getting-a-schengen-visa-addition-of-a-country and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes she will pass through immigration in Helsinki.

Itinerary changes can sometimes create problems (e.g. if you go to a completely different place without warning or show up somewhere unexpected with no ticket to your final destination) but in this case the change is so small and understandable that there is absolutely no reason it should be an issue. Incidentally, even if your girlfriend would have planned a layover in Finland from the get go, she would still have needed to get a Swedish visa that would be undistinguishable from her current visa.