# Hotel reservation after having visa

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel, bookings

I already have my multiple-entry Schengen visa.

When I applied, I gave them the hotel reservation from booking.com (not paid) and they granted the visa.

But now my friend invited me to stay at his home so I canceled my reservation after having the visa. There will be any problem with the control?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no stipulation that you must stay at the same hotel reservation for which you have shown in the visa application.

However, it is best you carry a proof that you will be staying at your friend's home (for example, a letter from him addressed to the embassy which issued the visa) would work along with their pertinent details (name, address, permanent resident number/id number/etc.)

This is in case the border officers ask for proof of accommodation. Keep in mind that a visa is not a guarantee of entry, it is just a permit to request entry at the border - so the immigration officer is well within their rights to deny you entry even if you have a "valid" visa.