# Honeymoon Travel to Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, italy

I am planning to travel to Italy in November for my honeymoon. I have a couple of doubts:

1. I have the ITR for 1 year only, as I was doing my MBA before that. The eligibility documents lists 3 year ITR. How can I clear this requirement?
2. I would apply for the visa in September, clearly I would be unmarried at that time. So, do I show separate bank statements for my wife and myself? How do I prove that we are going for a honeymoon to them?
3. Any minimum amount required in bank, like a minimum cut off balance

Comment: What is the ITR? [Your question 3 already has an answer here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab).

Comment: What is your citizenship? Is this question about visas or something else? Who are you showing things/proving things to?

Comment: The answer linked to by @JoErNanO is for UK visas but certainly a good read for you.

Comment: ITR is Income tax returns and by the OPs name I'd say the OP is an Indian Citizen.

Comment: I've down-voted your question since you do not specify key points: your citizenship and country of residence. It's impossible to answer your question without that information and nobody wants to play detective.

Comment: While every question from a first time OP can be improved, this question is very clear to many people, has a workable and personalized answer, and might have had more if it were left open. Perhaps the site needs a new reason - "put on hold as unclear to a select few."

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation (not exactly the same) around this time an year ago, I'd moved to the `US` for work and came back to India to get married.

My wife and I wanted to visit the UK and Ireland for our honeymoon. We'd applied for UK visas separately as single individuals, didn't mention marriage or honeymoon in the application. I'd applied in `NY` whereas my wife had done so in `Bangalore`. Since both of us work, we had adequate financial means on our own it wasn't a problem and we got our visas.
The visit thereafter was smooth too.

I'd recommend you do the same if your circumstances are similar, if however your wife isn't working then I'd recommend waiting till the wedding and applying together after that.

<del>Another side note (I don't recomment this course of action but you should know about this) : Since this is schengen if you feel one country's requirements are more stringent than another then you could apply for one which has easier requirements. I know a friend and his wife who visited Italy and even when they were applying from `NY` they had to go for an in person interview, went smoothly for them. I'm thinking `Greece` or `Spain` can do with tourists, god knows their economy needs it.</del>

Comment: Your last piece of advice needs a note of caution - people have had their visas cancelled when entering/exiting from a Schengen state that was never on their itenary.

Comment: Noted found this - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa

It seems like the wording on this is vague. I'll strike off that section, since I'm not an expert at this I'll just share my experience and let the OP decide for them if it helps or not.

Comment: @nikhil What wording do you find vague?  I don't see any; there is a well defined procedure for determining which country is "competent" to handle a Schengen visa application.  Gray areas may arise when plans change after the application has been filed, but that is caused more by an *absence* of wording.

Comment: This seemed vague and unenforceable to me - "A visa shall be annulled where it becomes evident that the conditions for issuing it were not met at the time when it was issued". In this particular case this would mean if the OP and Fiancee would apply separately then that would become invalid after marriage as the conditions change. They couldn't apply together as they aren't married and plan to travel when they are.

Comment: @nikhil - no, for a single-entry visa (which is probably what OP would get), you have to supply an itenary - what the OP intends to do, and where they intend to do it. The application *has* to be made to the "main destination" nation of the trip - if you apply anywhere else, it will just be sent back and told to send it to the right place. If OP then travels to different places (or purposes) than in the itenary, that would count as that - as the applicant would be considered guilty of deception at the time of application.