# Changing travel plans after getting a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe

I'm planning to go backpacking with a couple of friends and plan on visiting Netherlands, Germany, Czech Republic, Hungary, Poland, Latvia and Estonia.

Since I am from India, I don't want to take a risk of a visa rejection by showing this plan which stretches for 25-30 days. So:

1. Can I show my travel plans for Germany during the Oktoberfest and then change my plans after getting the visa? My entry/exit country will still remain the same.
2. Should I show an itinerary of the same number of days as per my original plan or can I just show a 8 day trip and then change it once I get my visa?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can make minor changes but you should not change your plans so drastically, especially if you have a single entry visa (which is likely as a first-time applicant). In practice, if you enter and leave through the same country, you are very unlikely to run into problems ([although it's possible](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa/44262#44262)). See also [this answer to another question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782).

But if you really intend to tour several countries from the get go, it's a bad idea to lie about it. You run the risk of contradicting yourself and damaging your credibility. And if you provide a plan for an 8-day trip, you are likely to get a visa valid for 8 days (or possibly 10 or 12 to give you a bit of leeway) and will not be able to stay for 30 days on it.

Comment: If I show a few countries in my plan, I will get a multiple entry visa, right? I'm a bit confused because if I show my original plan, there might be an higher chance of rejection.

Comment: @user44548 And if you show a false plan, then there is a higher chance of being refused entry at the border. Don't do this.

Comment: If you get a visa on the basis of an 8 day trip to visit Oktoberfest (and they happen to give you a visa that lasts longer) and then show up at the border looking like you're outfitted for a 30 day backpacking trip, you're going to have big problems. Lying on your visa application is a bad idea. And no, if you show a few countries in your plan, you will not be guaranteed a multiple entry visa, because the entire Schengen area works as one "country" for the purpose of entering and exiting.

Comment: Ok, the best that I can think of now is booking a refundable airfare + refundable hotels and show them the actual plan. Do I need to book my bus tickets too or can I do that once I get the visa? (I'd like to avoid all costs which are not refundable). Also, can I change the hotels to hostels/airbnb once I get the visa?

Comment: I currently have about $2500 in my bank account since I don't keep my funds liquid. I have decent mutual fund and stock market investments. Will this also be a negative point as one might think that $2500 won't be adequate for a 25 day backpacking trip? I could also show proof that my dad would be sponsoring my trip, in case that helps my chances of getting a visa. My age is 23, btw.