# Hostel reservation for schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, hostels, hostelworld

I am planning to go to Spain and I want to get schengen visa issued by Spanish consulate.

I tried to talk to travel agency and they told me that spanish embassy doesn't accept fake bookings (so a fake booking is not an option).

I will stay in a hostel that I have booked through hostel world. I have reservation and I will pay full price when I arrive. The hostel booking also allows free cancellation, up to 1 day before check-in.

Can this be problem? Will my visa be rejected because of this?

Please advise me on what I must do.

Comment: Zakk, did you get the visa ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of your Schengen visa application, you are asked to provide proof of accommodation. A fake booking certainly will not work, because a fake booking is not a proof of accommodation, because it is fake.

However, a hostel booking, regardless of how cheap or expensive, regardless of the cancelation policy, and regardless of where you booked it, is a proof of accommodation. It should therefore satisfy the requirements. Tens of thousands  people travel every year to the Schengen and stay in hostels. It is a perfectly acceptable proof of accommodation. There is no reason that a visa should be rejected on these grounds in any reasonable interpretation of the Schengen rules.

Be warned that if you choose to make a booking at a fancier place and then cancel it after your visa is issued, you are in theory committing visa fraud. Although you are allowed to change your plans for legitimate reasons, there are unconfirmed but numerous reports that some consuls in Russia and Ukraine annul visas if hotel bookings are canceled immediately after the visa is issued. For more on this, read user ach's answer to this question: [Can I change my route and hotel reservation after getting a Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa)

Comment: I saw some threads in the internet saying that the booking must be not refundable, that made ask this question also.
Thanks for clearing things out.