# Can I change hotel after getting a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, portugal

I need some information regarding hotel booking in Portugal. I booked hotels (with free cancellation) from booking.com in Lisbon and Porto before applying for a visa and submitted this booking information when applying.

Now I am getting better deals from different websites for better, cheaper hotels. Can I cancel the hotels I booked before and book the new hotels in the same city, same date and same duration? Will it cause any issue in the future?

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-route-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa/44262#44262