# What are the consequences of changing Schengen itineraries?

Tags: schengen-visas, france, schedule-change, visa-shopping

I had a Schengen visa issued by France but did not visit France; instead, I visited Norway. I was under the impression that holding a Schengen visa from any member country allows travel to any country within the area. (This is against visa rules. I couldn't conduct proper research and applied based on my relatives' advice, which may fall under visa shopping. Another reason I chose France was that I was told it's easier to get a visa from the French embassy).

Now, I want to know if I apply for a Schengen visa again, will I face rejection? If so, under which category would the rejection fall? Could it result in a ban? I am concerned about this because I need to travel to Schengen countries for work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are little more nuanced (or even confusing), see [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In your case, I wouldn't worry too much. Remember that the authorities don't have a full record of your travels. Your passport should bear Norwegian entry and exit stamps but the authorities have no easy way to see whether you stayed there or travelled onwards to another Schengen country afterwards and I don't think France is especially concerned about it.

With that said, it's possible to [get in trouble for changing plans and cancelling a booking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44258/can-i-change-my-itinerary-and-hotel-reservation-after-getting-a-schengen-visa). However, if something like that was happening to you, you would have noticed (because it requires cancelling the visa).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying. I’m concerned in my future visas. Will it be a problematic for me?

Comment: @usmanfaleel See the final link in the answer. In theory using a visa for a completely different purpose than the one given in the application can be problematic. If you have to give details of your previous trip in your next application, or if eg Norwegian and French rules require hotels etc to notify guest information, the authorities *might* find out about the change. There’s really no way to know other than to apply and hope for the best

Comment: @usmanfaleel As I wrote, "in your case I wouldn't worry too much". France does not routinely check hotel bookings or cancel visas because plans have changed and if that was the case, you would have noticed so it's unlikely to be problematic. There isn't much I can add to that and I don't think anybody can tell you definitely that it won't ever be a problem. But it's unlikely, for all the reasons I mentioned.

Comment: @Traveller Hi thanks for valuable insight.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for your detailed and clear explanations. Would you know in case if they reject, what would be the reject reason they would give me. Will it be a fatal one restricting my future travel. I am more concerned on that.

Comment: France or other Schengen countries might care if they thought you were visa-shopping.