# What should I write in "Member states of destination" on Schengen visa applications?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, applications

I am traveling to Paris staying there for 5 days then flying to Spain and staying there for 10 days.

My understanding is that since Spain is where I am spending most of the time then I should apply for the visa in the spanish embassy.

But how about these fields in my case, How should I fill them?
"Member states of destination" & "Member state of first entry"...
Should they be "Spain" and "France" respectively?

Comment: I believe this one covers some of your questions...
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Comment: Thanks. I saw this post before but it doesnt mention these fields in the visa application in specific.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Seriously?!! no one filled a VISA application before?!!

Comment: One is plural and the other one is singular: you can only enter one state but you can visit more that one. So I imagine entry would be Spain, and member States would be Spain and France in your case.

Comment: Thanks Jo, My first entry is actually France. But yes, I finally figured out the information you stated from other forums.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Member states of destination

is plural and

> member state of first entry

is singular for a simple reason: **you can only enter Schengen from one state but you can visit more that one member state whilst in the Area**. So I imagine that in your case first entry would be France, and member destination states would be France and Spain.