# "Member state(s) of destination" confusion in Belgium online Schengen visa application

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, tourist-visas

I am an Indian passport holder. I am planning to apply for a Belgium visa for a conference. I am also planning to visit Spain after this conference.

In the online application form, I need to fill up a box called:  "Member State(s) of destination". But in the answer box, they have provided provision to enter only one EU country name. When I enter 'Belgium', then I cannot enter 'Spain' without cancelling 'Belgium' first.

When I click further information it says: "Please indicate which Schengen Member state you are visiting."

Which country should I enter then?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this a a dupe. That answer seems to indicate you can put more than one entry in the field. Here, the OP is saying only one country will fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are frustrated because the form does not have enough room to list multiple countries.

> When I enter 'Belgium', then I cannot enter 'Spain' without
>   cancelling 'Belgium' first.

You can enter their international abbreviations like this...

[image]

be = Belgium, es = Spain, it = Italy, and so on.  When the consular officials see those abbreviations, they will know what to do.

---

For the case where you are presented with an immutable drop down list for which the only possibility is to select a single answer, then your strategy would be to select the country to which you are making the application (in your case Belgium). You can use the free form text to list the others in your itinerary.

Because a single choice drop-down list is a fallacy given that the answer can be multiple countries, the consular staff will eventually recognise it and have their IT unit make a change to the underlying programme.  They do not issue  refusals for this type of operational inconsistency anyway. You can print out this answer and attach it to your application if doing so will increase your comfort level.

---

Related: [What should I write in "Member states of destination" on Schengen visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47846/what-should-i-write-in-member-states-of-destination-on-schengen-visa-applicati)

Comment: The form is online and I can select only from the drop down menu options provided. I cannot write 'be', 'es' in the answer box. Only full names of EU countries are in the drop down menu.(I even tried to put a comma after the country name. It doesn't do anything. It seems only one name is provided to be entered in the box) :-/

Comment: @patel that's bad. Would you provide the URL of the form? I would like to be sure it's not a scam site. What's the URL?

Comment: http://www.vfsglobal.com/Belgium/India/how-to-apply.html  <--- this is the VFS site for Belgium visa. Go to step 3, find the orange highlighted text "online visa application form" It takes you to another site https://visaonweb.diplomatie.be/     I made an account there.

Comment: In the form, the Member states question is number 22

Comment: @patel yes, I can see the problem. The form is wrong. It comes from a poor set of requirements and inadequate user testing.  See the revised answer above.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer and also taking the time to check my form. I will add my extra EU countries in my itinerary as you suggested. Have a great week!

Comment: @patel all part of the service. Don't forget to print out this answer!