# Do I need a transit visa for Frankfurt if I (an Indian Citizen) am travelling from India to Nice (France)?

Tags: schengen, transit

Travelling via Lufthansa. (Delhi->Frankfurt->Nice)

There would be a waiting time of 6 hours for  my flight from Frankfurt to Nice.

Do I need a transit VISA?

Information from Lufthansa website is not clear.

Comment: What type of visa do you have for your visit to Nice?

Comment: @CGCampbell Won't matter much.

Comment: Also related: [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Comment: @Karlson this is not a duplicate of the question.  The questioner is not actually transiting in the Schengen area; the final destination is *in* the Schengen area.

Answer (score 2):

If you are visiting Nice then you must already have permission to enter the Schengen area. Frankfurt is also part of the Schengen area, so the visa that gets you into Nice will cover it. You will clear immigration in Frankfurt and then fly to Nice without further checks.