# Can I travel through Schengen zone with a visa obtained for presentation of an academic paper in a conference?

Tags: visas, schengen

If I obtain a visa to present my work at a language conference in Poland, will I be allowed to travel to other member states as well?

Comment: As long as you are still really going to Poland at some point and you have got a visa with sufficient flexibility (no unusual restriction to a single country, sufficient length of stay and period of validity), it should be possible. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa for all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- once you have a visa, you're allowed to combine the conference trip with other business or incidental tourism in the Schengen area -- as long as you conform with with the length-of-stay and valid-until restrictions on the visa *and* you're still actually going to the conference as part of the trip.

In particular, you can travel *through* other Schengen states on your way to and from Poland.

(This holds for both single-entry and multiple-entry visas, except with a single-entry visa you must be careful not to follow an itinerary that will take you temporarily out of the Schengen area during the trip).