# Airport transit visa for Munich, if I have Long Stay visa type D for France (sauf CTOM)

Tags: schengen, transit, france, germany, long-stay-visas

I am an Indian citizen and I was granted a visa from the French Consulate. It says that my visa type is Long Stay "D" valid for France (sauf CTOM).

I am going to Nice (France) via Munich (Germany), would I need a transit visa for Germany ?

Comment: To clarify, you transit via Germany en route from India to France, or do you have other stops? In the former case, this is not really a transit for visa purposes: you will enter the Schengen area in Germany, which is possible even though your visa was issued by France.

Comment: This is an unclear question. Please tell us exactly what you are wanting to do. Also, please note, if you are wanting information on going to France to start your long duration stay, this really should be in [expatriates.se].

Comment: Hi,
To be exact, I am going from India to Nice via. Munich. My VISA category is type D  valid for France (sauf CTOM). My flight is New Delhi -Munich and then from Munich-Nice. My question is simply that, would I require a transit VISA at the Munich airport ?

Comment: As I said above, transit visas do not apply to you because you will need to pass border control in Munich. The question is whether you can enter Germany on a type D visa issued by France, and I am unable to find the answer. A type D visa entitles you to *visit* Germany (for up to 90 days in any 180 days period), but I don't know about *entering* Germany from outside the Schengen area. You may want to edit the question to make this clear (or I can do it if you want), but it may be considered off-topic here as @CGCampbell said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Comment: @Vince Not a duplicate, we are talking about a national visa for France, not a Schengen visa.

Comment: @fkraiem OK fair enough, what do you think about this then:  [Do I need a visa to transit in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Neither because, as I explained, OP will need to formally enter the Schengen area in Germany. Schengen transit visas are for travelers who do not formally enter the Schengen area because they go from one non-Schengen country to another (this is why I deleted my previous answer, Schengen transit visas are irrelevant here). The real question is as I stated above: can one enter the Schengen area with a type D visa issued by a Schengen country which is not the country of entry? I have not found any other question about this (and it may be off-topic).

Answer (score 7):

This is possible by article 5 paragraph 4(a) of the [Schengen Borders Code (Regulation (EC) No 562/2006)](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2006:105:0001:0032:EN:PDF)

> third-country nationals who do not fulfil all the conditions laid down in paragraph 1 but hold a residence permit or a re-entry visa issued by one of the Member States or, where required, both documents, shall be authorised to enter the territories of the other Member States for transit purposes so that they may reach the territory of the Member State which issued the residence permit or re-entry visa, unless their names are on the national list of alerts of the Member State whose external borders they are seeking to cross and the alert is accompanied by instructions to refuse entry or transit;