# Schengen visa control on the Eurostar

Tags: schengen

I am a non-UK & non-EU citizen. I am travelling on the Eurostar from London to Paris. I have a UK visa & a Schengen visa issued from Switzerland, not France.  Would the UK immigration in London allow me to board the Eurostar to Paris if my Schengen visa first entry is France, not Switzerland?

Comment: No, it's not a problem, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Comment: Note that you will obviously enter France long before reaching Paris, in Coquelles or Fréthun, near Calais, and you will complete the immigration formalities even earlier, at the station in London. Once you are in the train, you are cleared to go wherever you like.

Comment: Would the UK immigration in London allow me to board the Euro star to Paris if my Schengen visa first entry is France and not Switzerland ?

Comment: Your passport and visa will be checked by French (not British) officers in London. And, no, it's not a problem, as I wrote above.