# French Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, portugal, moroccan-citizens

Me and my Moroccan friend are currently planning a holiday to Portugal (I'm a british citizen). We're slightly concerned though, that because her Schengen visa has been issued via the French embassay and is a 'French shengen' visa, that she has to go to France first and then travel to Portugal.

Can anyone confirm whether she would need to go to France first(and then figure out a way to Portugal), or if she can just go straight from Morocco to Portugal.

Comment: It's generally fine, although it might depend a bit on the details (e.g. what kind of visa – single or multiple entry, whether she has been to France previously, etc.), see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782 for more. How come your friend has a French Schengen visa?

Comment: Has she used the visa before for a travel to France? And is she planning to go to France in this trip (later on?)

Comment: However, [she might be denied boarding](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50944/boarding-denied-as-the-final-itinerary-did-not-include-the-schengen-visa-issuing)