# Student visa rejected for Portugal. Can I apply for Schengen tourist visa to Estonia?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, portugal, estonia, visa-rejections

I am Indian by nationality and live and work in Portugal. My boyfriend is also Indian, and he lives in India.

Recently my boyfriend applied for a Portugal student visa and got rejected due to low funds, but he had 8,000 EUR in his bank account. Apart from that they have also mentioned there is a risk of migration due to low funds.

Since then there were many students I came into contact with whose Portugal visa got rejected, so I think it is impossible for him to apply for another one.

In spite of that, can he apply for an Estonian Schengen tourist visa? Will he be able to get it? Or will there be a rejection again? I heard that Estonia has a lower rejection rate.

As he was thinking he would get visa for Portugal, he left his job. Now if he applies what are the chances for his visa to be approved? And is 200,000 INR enough to show as a proof of funds?

Comment: In order to apply for an Estonian visa, he would have to be traveling to Estonia.

Comment: Yes He will be travelling to Estonia and I will join him in Estonia for the trip. I want to know if he can apply now or leave. If he applies again and get rejected then it will be bad reputation for his passport as he will have two rejections.

Comment: I see that tuition costs are low in Portugal--does that include international students? Was the university he applied to going to give him any money? If not, the government probably wants to see around $1000 per month for living expenses for 9 months--he doesn't have enough.

Answer (score 4):

> **can he apply for an Estonian Schengen tourist visa?**

He can certainly apply.

If visiting Portugal was his main intent and would be the country where he spends most of his time, Estonian officials may think he should apply to Portugal.

See top answer to [Would Netherlands refuse entry for a Schengen visa issued by the French embassy?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51112/13639)

If he plans to spend the majority of his EU visit in Estonia, then it is appropriate to apply there.

It is almost certain that Estonian officials will know all about his prior refusal by Portugal and will scrutinise his application with extra thoroughness.

> **As he was thinking he would get visa for Portugal, he left his job.**

Unfortunately that is one of the worst things he could have done if he is subsequently to apply for a tourist visa.

He needs to prove that he has strong compelling motives for returning to India. Being unemployed weakens his case enormously.

Since he has strong motives for *not* returning to India (e.g. having a girlfriend residing in the EU) - his case looks bleak to me.

Creating a history of, or impression of, visa-shopping would only make things worse.

> **is 200,000 INR enough to show as a proof of funds?**

I believe it is irrelevant. He ideally needs to show a steady income over many months with steadily accumulating savings. He needs to show that the costs of his proposed visit to the EU is proportionate to the unspent part of his annual income.

A bank account showing the sudden unexplained arrival of 200,000 INR is likely to destroy his chances of obtaining a visa.

See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/13639) - Although that is about UK visas, I suspect similar considerations apply to applications for Schengen visas.

Comment: He did not apply for tourist visa to Portugal. He applied for Student visa and his course duration was 1 year and his job had 2 months notice period due to which he had to resign in prior and the Portugal embassy delayed in giving us an answer by a month so we aware not sure about anything.

Comment: @Meowstar: thanks, I've updated the answer. It is still true that making himself unemployed is probably detrimental to any application for the Estonian Schengen tourist visa you asked about. If he can get his job reinstated, or find another, that should help.