# Can I enter Poland with Italy Schengen visa without entering Italy?

Tags: schengen

Can I enter Poland with Italy Schengen visa without entering through Italy, my visa is multiable. My friend here told to first enter Italy then go to Romania. Is my friend right?

Comment: Are you going to Poland or Romania? The rules are different! For Poland, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa as pointed out by @Willeke.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Poland and Italy are both schengen countries. With your schengen visa you can visit Poland without any problems.

Refer to this information: http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/index_en.htm