# Should I follow what was mentioned in the “duration of stay” or in the "validity of the visa"?

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm from Tunisia and I got a Schengen visa from the Austrian Embassy for  28 days, the “duration of stay”, and the number of entries is 1. But the validity of the visa is from 02/08/2015 to 13/09/2015.

Do I have to stay only 28 days, for example from 02/08/2015 to 29/08/2015 or can I stay there until 12/09/2015 ?

And if I have got to stay only 28 days, then can I choose the days of stay, that's mean can I stay in Austria for example from 09/08/2015 to 05/09/2015?

Comment: I think it means you can use any 28 days between those dates. Obviously if the visa is valid until 12/09 I don't see why it would be a problem if you stayed until then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to follow both, i.e. stay at most 28 days at some time between 02/08/2015 and 13/09/2015. Therefore, you cannot stay longer than 28 days on this visa in any event and if you have not used your 28 days by the 13th of September, you must leave anyway.

You also have to respect the number of entries, which means that if you enter some time in August and leave a few days later, you cannot use this visa anymore and you lose the benefit of the rest of the maximum period of stay.

09/08/2015 to 05/09/2015 is indeed 28 days and within the period of validity of your visa, so that's fine.

In principle, the conditions of your visa should be based on the information you submitted with your application and allow you to complete your trip as intended. The validity is typically a little longer to give you some flexibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I still have one question.
As I mentioned I'm from Tunisia and I got a Schengen visa from the Austrian Embassy for 28 days, the “duration of stay”,  and the number of entries is 1.
Can I visit another european country like Germany or France for a couple days for example I spend 20 daus in Austrian  and 4 days in germany and 3 days in France then I go back to Tunisia? Is there any problem if I do that?
And If yes, then can I take my fly from Tunisia to Berlin? Or I have got to go first to Austria?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HamidBessi All this is in principle allowed but on the other hand making a lot of changes to your plans might create problems. You can visit another country or enter through Germany but it's important that you spend most of the time in Austria and basically do what you said you would do, especially with a single-entry visa. Also be ready to explain your plans again and have some proof with you if challenged at the border. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782 for more details on all this.

Answer (score 15):

You have to follow both.

You may enter the Schengen area at any time during the 43-day period of its validity, but you may only stay 28 days in total, and you must leave on or before 13/09/2015, even if you have not used all 28 days.

Also, since this is a single entry visa, you cannot leave the Schengen area and return on this visa, even if you have used fewer than 28 days.

However, using the visa properly establishes a good history and makes it more likely that you will receive a double entry or multiple entry visa with longer validity periods in future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I still have one question.
As I mentioned I'm from Tunisia and I got a Schengen visa from the Austrian Embassy for 28 days, the “duration of stay”,  and the number of entries is 1.
Can I visit another european country like Germany or France for a couple days for example I spend 20 daus in Austrian  and 4 days in germany and 3 days in France then I go back to Tunisia? Is there any problem if I do that?
And If yes, then can I take my fly from Tunisia to Berlin? Or I have got to go first to Austria?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HamidBessi See http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13362/3221