# Schengen multivisa - duration each 180 days or total?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

assuming a person has a Schengen Visa with MULT number of entries, duration of stay for 30 days and it's valid over a year. Is the "duration of stay" limited for each 180 days a year, or is it the total amount of days, after using it the visa becomes invalid? According to the visa code

> 4. ‘DURATION OF VISIT ... DAYS’ heading:
>
> This heading indicates the number of days during which the visa holder
>   may stay in the territory for which the visa is valid. This stay may
>   be continuous or, depending on the number of days authorised, spread
>   over several periods between the dates mentioned under 2, bearing in
>   mind the number of entries authorised under 3. The number of days
>   authorised is written in the blank space between ‘DURATION OF VISIT’
>   and ‘DAYS’, in the form of two digits, the first of which is a zero if
>   the number of days is less than 10. The maximum number of days that
>   may be entered under this heading is 90. When a visa is valid for more
>   than six months, the duration of stays is 90 days in every six-month
>   period.

This 30 days seem to be equal to 90 by default...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. Seems like a language problem. Could you try to explain it in a different way?

Comment: @Fiksdal I think what he's asking is if the validity of a multiple-entry visa is for each stay or all stays combined

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, until you come back to edit your question and make it clearer. However I think the answer for your question is that you have "duration of visit: 30 days" then that is 30 days total, summing all visits, and has nothing to do with the 90/180 rule. See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51221/32134

Comment: @mts but the visa code specifies that visas valid for a period of longer than 180 days shall have a duration of stay of "90."  So the visa seems not to comply with the code.  Yevgeniy: Can you please scan your visa, redact the personal information (cover it with black bars), and add it to your question?  Thanks.

Comment: It's not the first time I am hearing about something like this but the confusion stems from the fact that such a visa is not supposed to exist. The consulate should have either restricted the period of validity to less than six months or put “90” or even “XXX” as maximum duration. Their mistake makes the interpretation of the rule somewhat ambiguous but the safest one for you is to assume that you are only allowed 30 days in total over the whole year on this visa. You could apply for another visa to return earlier however as you would be far from exhausting the overall 90/180 limit.

Comment: @mts Actually, it's related in at least two ways: Long-validity (6+ months) Schengen uniform visas are supposed to follow the 90/180 rule (as shown by the text cited by the OP) and the 90/180 limit also applies to visas in that it's not possible to issue a Schengen uniform visa that would allow the holder to circumvent it (even if you have several shorter visas, the 90/180 applies across all your Schengen short-term visas, with one exception: LTV visas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your total time in the Schengen during the visa validity (1 year) can be max 1 month. However you can enter as many times as you want during that year, provided you do not stay longer than 1 month in total.