# Is the Romanian Visit visa (C/VV) expiry date the last day I can cross the border or the last day I can stay?

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, romania, 90-180-visa-rules, visa-expiration

Is the expiry date on that visit visa the last day I can cross the Romanian border, or is it the last day I can stay in Romania, in which I have to leave the country before expiry? I've seen people talking about problems that you might have if you attempt to leave an EU country with an expired visa. I am aware that the maximum amount of days I can stay in Romania is tied to the 90-180 day rule.

Comment: Also worth reading: [https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51221/should-i-follow-what-was-mentioned-in-the-duration-of-stay-or-in-the-validity](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51221/should-i-follow-what-was-mentioned-in-the-duration-of-stay-or-in-the-validity) on the difference between validity and duration of stay.

Answer (score 8):

In Romania and in the Schengen states, the visa validity is the indicator of the **last** day you can be in the country. This is unlike the US, where legal status and visa validity are two separate concepts and you can stay in the country with an expired visa

From [AXA](https://www.axa-schengen.com/en/schengen-visa/visa-validity) (this is for Schengen, but Romania closely follow the visa policy of Schengen due to its EU membership) :

> The validity period of your visa indicates how long you can use your visa. The dates are mentioned on your visa sticker. It will have a ‘From’ date, from which you are permitted to enter the Schengen Area, and an ‘Until’ date - the date on which you must leave - the end of its validity period.