# Schengen Visa Multiple entry

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry

I live in London and I have been issued a Schengen multiple entry Visa from The Italian Consulate from 18 Aug to 1 Oct. My Holiday to Italy is from 18Aug to 23 Aug. Thereafter I will return to London.

In september I want to visit other countries in Schengen Area like France, Switzerland etc. But this time I will not be going to Italy. Will this be a problem with Port of Entry?

Comment: For a multiple entry visa, where you already visited the country which issued the visa, it should be no problem.

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa