# Air travel between Schengen countries and single-entry Schengen visas

Tags: schengen

I applied for schengen visa via Norway embassy. I got a single entry visa (even though I asked for multiple entry). Now my plan actually is to land in France (Paris), travel through Belgium to Amsterdam by road and then fly from Amsterdam to Bergen in Norway. I am curious to know whether flying from Amsterdam would be considered as exiting the Schengen state even though I am flying to another Schengen state?

I know it is OK to travel from one Schengen member country to another within the visa tenure and without exiting the Schengen states. I did it before last year by entrying into Austria and traveled through Czech Republic, Germany and then reaching Switzerland (all by road) and then flew back to Dubai where I reside.

**But I am really unsure of air travel that how is it taken when you fly from one Schengen state to another?**

Comment: I flew from Italy to Greece (both Schengen states) in 2009 and didn't have my passport checked. So from that I'd say that you're probably fine.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/52129#52129

Answer (score 5):

Yes, only crossing an *external* border count as an entry or exit and air travel is no different in this regard. Airports in the Schengen area have often been reorganised to process Schengen flights separately, typically with no official passport check and occasionally with no ID check of any kind. Airlines still occasionally insist on seeing a visa but since you have one, it should not create any problem.