# If I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa, is it ok to exit Schengen area without visiting the visa-issuing country on the first visit?

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry

I am an Indian citizen working in Malaysia and have been issued a multiple entry Schengen visa, valid for two months, to attend a conference in Vienna from the Austrian Embassy, as I will be staying there for longest number of days. My flight is Kuala Lumpur - Frankfurt (transit) - Paris and returning via same route. Frankfurt will thus be my first port of entry in Schengen area. I will be staying in Paris for 4 days then go to UK (with a separate visa issued) for 6 days then back to Paris. Then go from Paris to Vienna to attend the conference on my second entry in Schengen area.

So my concern is -  I will be exiting Paris without visiting Austria which issued me the visa, to go to London, then re-enter Paris after London and go to Vienna on my second entry in Schengen area to attend the conference. Is it OK to make an exit (although for a short duration) without visiting country issuing Schengen visa the first time, and my intention and purpose to visit it subsequently remains intact and I have conference itinerary and registration details to prove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Answer (score 4):

The general principles described in my answer to [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782) apply. Your visa is valid for all countries in the Schengen area and any number of entries/exits, the only concern is that you want to avoid the impression that you lied to obtain the visa.

There is a small twist in your scenario in that you will leave and reenter the Schengen area before reaching your main destination but there is no formal rule against that. Having a multiple-entry visa and an entry clearance of the UK as well is also a small plus, border guards are more likely to be interested in people who only have a single-entry visa.

If there are questions, being able to show Austria is still your main destination, ideally with tickets and conference registration details in hand (do not necessarily show them immediately, but have them with you if necessary), is important. Just be genuine and explain your plan clearly and all should be fine.

Incidentally, it's most likely to come up during the first entry in Germany, possibly when reentering France but probably not on exit.