# Schengen Visa for Switzerland, but travel to Amsterdam & Paris

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, switzerland, amsterdam

I am planning to visit Europe in November. My initial plan was to be in Switzerland for the entire duration of the trip. I have got the visa as well. But I wish to go to Amsterdam for two nights out of 9 days and one night to Paris (travel by train). The remaining is in Switzerland only. Is it okay to travel with the visa?

Comment: The question is exactly not the same but you should find an answer in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782

Comment: You can travel to any country within the Schengen zone with your visa.