# USA → Spain → Romania: No visa?

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, romania

All the questions (and other websites) about visiting Romania are confusing.  But Romania has published a list of countries whose citizens do not need a visa, and USA is one. So, it seems that I do not need any visa for Romania, and I can ignore all the stuff about going there with a Schengen visa and only staying five days.

But again, this is confusing—have I got it right?

(update): well, the comments and answers eased my mind until I read

[Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

and

[Can I enter Romania based on unused multiple entry Schengen visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70887/can-i-enter-romania-based-on-unused-multiple-entry-schengen-visa)

Now I am confused again.  I entered Spain 5 April 2016 and am scheduled to fly into Romania 1 July 2016.  That's four days short of ninety in Schengen.  Plans are to spend more than four days in Romania.  One or more of the answers in the above questions makes it sound like Romania will count the eighty-some days already used.  I have no visa other than the stamp the Spanish guy made without even looking at any other pages in my passport.

Comment: you have it right. But the 90/180 rule still applies. Do you need a formal answer or are you good?

Comment: @GayotFow Romania's 90/180 rule, right, not the Schengen one?

Comment: That's good, as is the answer below.  However, feel free to add to it if you think it will help someone else.  What makes it confusing is that some pages give the impression that entering from a "real" Schengen country somehow changes things.  (Going over land from Spain to Romania.)

Comment: @GayotFow A formal answer is still preferred, so it can be accepted and the question won't appear on the unanswered list. Not an issute in this case, since somebody's already posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correct: as an American citizen you do not need a visa to visit Romania.** When in doubt, check the State Department travel website:

> U.S. citizen visitors are granted 90 days of stay without a visa within a given six-month period.

From: http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/romania.html

Comment: Question just became less important to me :-) http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72045/usa-citizen-wants-to-stay-in-spain-a-little-longer?noredirect=1#comment155675_72045