# USA citizen wants to stay in Spain a little longer

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, spain, visa-free-entry, visa-extensions

I have been in Spain since 6 April 2016, meaning that (I suppose) I am expected to leave Schengen on or before 5 July.

I have a ticket to Romania (not part of Schengen) 1 July but I do not have a ticket back to USA, and I would prefer to remain in Spain till mid-July.

"visa extension spain" here in Travel gets 13 hits of which five are obviously irrelevant.  I do not think I am duplicating any of the others because of the following differences:

- USA citizen
- Spain (not some other country)
- No specific visa, i.e., I just flew to BCN without any prior paperwork and they let me in.

I am planning to request an extension at the *Comisaría General de Extranjería* in Logroño on Monday, but if anyone has knowledge of a better approach, I'd appreciate it.  If I don't succeed in making it official, it's no big deal for me to leave on the fifth, but it would cost more and it would interfere with my research toward applying for six-month residency next year.

Comment: In general, you don't get very far trying to extend visa-free stays.

Comment: @CMaster: that comment doesn't surprise me, but unfortunately, I only realized yesterday that I am not likely to complete my investigations before the fifth, much less the first.  So I am hoping …

Comment: You actually have to leave on the 4th, since the day of entry counts as one day. You have 25 days in April and 61 days in May and June, making 86 days and leaving only 4 days in July.

Comment: I know this is going to sound smart-alecky, but you do realize you're planing to request a visa extension, on a non-existant visa (visa-free)...

Comment: Well, yes and no.  I want to request official approval to stay past the fourth.  What name we put on it is not important.

Comment: Now trying to go back, but .... http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76654/staying-longer-than-ninety-days-in-spain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there are emergency-related circumstances, you **cannot** extend a visa-free stay in Schengen. Do visit the Comisaría General de Extranjería though and explain your situation, it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Nor, apparently, can you get a visa at all without first leaving and then working your butt off to assemble an application to come back.