# I have a schengen visa applied through german embassy and will be traveling from India to Dusseldorf (Germany) via Switzerland

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, switzerland

I have a schengen visa applied through german embassy and will be traveling from New Delhi (India) to Dusseldorf (Germany), with a layover in zurich, flying on swiss airline

Will immigration happen at Zurich or Dusseldorf? and would I need a transit visa or schengen will work.

Would a layover of 1 hours in Zurich be enough to require a change of planes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switzerland is a Schengen country, so immigration clearance will happen in Zurich. Assuming you are booked through on a single airline ticket, your bags should be checked through to Dusseldorf and you will not need to claim them in Zurich though.

You will not need a transit visa for Zurich, as your Schengen visa will be good for both Switzerland and Germany.

1 hour could well be tight, but assuming you are on a single ticket, the airline is responsible for getting you to Dusseldorf if you do miss your connection. If you are running out of time, you should speak to the airline staff, who should be able to help you make it or find you another flight.

Comment: so it mean that I can make first entry in zurich even if I have a Schengen visa via germany

Comment: @ankur Yes that's fine. See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa). You'll enter the Schengen area in Zurich, but Germany is still the main destination for your trip, so that's where your visa should come from. It's quite common.

Comment: @ankur, it's a great answer, but you don't need to say thanks in comments, it's better to vote or accept, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers