# First port of entry for Schengen visa holders

Tags: schengen

I hold a short stay visa issued by Switzerland. In my itinerary, I mentioned Zurich as the first port of entry. But, I would like to change my travel plan with Paris as the first port of entry and then to Switzerland (Zurich) where I stay for longer duration. Shall I be permitted?

Comment: [This answer to another question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782) covers this scenario as well. In short: It should be fine but it's best to have the tickets to and from Switzerland on hand to be able to show that it is really your main destination.