# Can I transit through Germany with an unused Schengen visa issued by Spain?

Tags: schengen, transit, germany, munich, fra

I am a **Indian citizen**, traveling to Mexico via Frankfurt (from Mumbai) with a multiple-entry Spanish Schengen visa. (The return journey would be Mexico-Munich-Mumbai.)

As per official [Mexican Visa authorities](https://embamex2.sre.gob.mx/india/index.php/es/visas) (link doesn't work anymore, but [here's an unofficial copy](https://www.visahq.in/mexico/)):

> ...Holders of any valid U.S.A., Canada, United Kingdom and Schengen
> Visas (any nationality) DO NOT require a visa to enter Mexico on
> tourist, business and transit purposes only....

And that was confirmed to me by the Mexican embassy also.

**I have applied for and gotten the Schengen visa, for the first time.**

But my query is:

I am not sure as I have never entered a Schengen country and the German authorities would consider my first point of entry as Germany and deny my entry as my Schengen visa was issued by Spanish authorities and on top of that I am travelling to Mexico!

Comment: I have edited your post to improve clarity, please review the edit and make sure it is true to your intentions. If it's not, roll it back or edit further.

Answer (score 8):

As an Indian national you would ordinarily need an Airport Transit Visa in order to make an airside transit at a German airport. However, holding a *valid* type C visa from any Schengen state *exempts you* from this requirement.

See the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), article 3(5)(a).

Whether you have the right paperwork for the transit will be checked by the *airline* rather than the German authorities. The airline is not competent to judge whether the reasons for issuing the visa still apply (which is what could create a problem at the border if you tried to *enter* the Schengen area on a visa that clearly doesn't match your stated plans); they merely check that you *have* a visa of the right kind.

And even so, logically the exemption from airport transit visas that comes with a type C visa will *practically always* be something you use on a *different* trip than the one your visa was issued for -- because on the trip your visa was issued for you won't need to *transit* anyway but to *enter* the Schengen area. So you're not using the exemption in a way it wasn't intended to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the response.Just need to clarify one thing.You have mentioned unused Schengen Visa issued by Spain.I would like to add Unused Schengen Visa issued for the first time! I have never been issued a schengen visa before this.                                   And also on my return Journey from Mexico (Mexico-Munich-Mumbai) can i enter Germany and stay there.Would that create a problem

Comment: @lizonceramicexport: It shouldn't matter that the visa is unused or whether you have had such visas before -- the airline doesn't know about that and have no reason to care.

Comment: @lizonceramicexport: As for making a trip into Germany on an unrelated (and unused-for-its-originalk-purpose) visa, it's a bit of a grey area. See [Relaxed's answer here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44782/16947) for discussion.