# Entry to Germany with Swiss national visa, staying for a week

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, switzerland, residency

As far as I know, it is possible to freely travel inside the Schengen zone with visa D of some EU country, using 90/180 rule (up to 90 days in 180 days). However, I have the following question: I have a study Swiss National visa, and would like to shortly visit my relative in Germany before start of my studies. However, I am worried about two things (in which this case differ from ones, which I found to be already discussed here):

- Although Switzerland is included in Schengen, it is not part of EU, so I am not completely sure if the same rules applied to Swiss National visa.
- Usually people enter other EU countries **after** they entered country which issued visa, and have registered there. So would it be a problem to enter Schengen via Germany, stay there for a week, and then from there go to Switzerland? Instructions from swiss embassy say "It allows you to travel to Switzerland; transiting other Schengen States is possible", from which it is clear that I can enter **through** Germany, but not clear, whether I can **stay** there for a week. I am worried, that at German border I can be asked to show my tickets to Switzerland, and the fact that the flight would be in a week from my entrance to Germany, could be a problem.

I would appreciate advise, if anybody had some similar issue before.

Comment: These rules definitely apply to Switzerland. I wouldn't be too concerned about the other bit.

Comment: I once crossed the Swiss-German border 4 times in one day, including a bike track nowhere near any sort of police.

Comment: There would be no problem at all. You would be able stay for a week in Germany before your main destination ie Switzerland

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's Switzerland or Germany - Schengen laws matter here, not EU laws. Voting to close as a dupe.

Comment: If I understood right, the question now is called "duplicate", referring to [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa) one. But that one is about usual Schengen visa, not National one (my case). And most of questions about using National 3-month visa to enter other EU countries are discussing visiting them already after entering state which issued visa, (and after registering there). So I thought this difference also can matter.
Anyway, I am happy if it's no problem to do the same in my case. Thanks for advises