# I have a UK visit visa, can it help acquiring a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

I am a Pakistani and have a UK visit visa till August 2017. Where should I apply for a Schengen visa from Karachi?

Comment: UK visa won't help you obtaining any other visas. And you should apply the visa to the country which you're going to visit.

Comment: Having acquired a visa for an affluent country is generally a positive factor in your immigration profile. It doesn't determine however whether you will get a Schengen.

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question in the body. The latter is covered by...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)

Comment: Yes, provided that you will be allowed to enter the UK **after** the Schengen visit. The Schengen officials will consider it much less likely that you'll become an illegal immigrant there if you could overstay in the UK.