# Travelling to Italy before heading to Greece

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino currently holding a Greece National Type D visa. Before traveling to Greece, however, I would like to stay in Italy for 3 weeks.

Will I have any problems at the Italian airport if I show up with this visa only? I was told I need to go to Greece before I could travel to Italy. I would like to know if anybody had a similar experience before.

Comment: @jcaron: probably not the same problem, as it may be a requirement to first arrive in the country that issued the visum.

Comment: @TomasBy, the last line of the quote is "You can also pass through other Schengen area countries on the way to your host country."

Comment: @jcaron: but that seems to be about going to another Schengen country when you are already in, ie through a third one. Or maybe you are right.

Comment: @TomasBy the host country is the visa issuing country and the OP can pass through other Schengen areas while on the way to the host country.

Comment: @Newton: if you follow the link you find the quote is from [this page](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/who-does-what/what-does-the-eu-do/already-in-the-eu_en) which is titled `Already in the EU' so I am still not 100% sure you can first arrive in a country different from the one that issued the visa.

Comment: @TomasBy have a look at the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407).  There is no requirement for the first arrival to be in the country issuing the visa.

Comment: @phoog: there is extensive discussion of this on the site. Some countries do not like if it is not, apparently.

Comment: @TomasBy Really?  The only evidence I've seen of people thinking such a rule exists points to airline staff, not immigration officials.

Comment: @phoog: [look here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa) for example.

Comment: @TomasBy everything on that page supports the conclusion that there is no such rule.  Finland is mentioned as an example of a country that is very sensitive about possible fraud in connection with short-stay visas, but that's not the same as a rule requiring first entry to be in the country of issue. In any event, the present question does not concern a short-stay visa.

Comment: @phoog: check the example which is currently 2nd from bottom. I saw something similar about a southern European country also (Greece?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72001/discussion-between-phoog-and-tomas-by).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're going to take up residence in Greece, making it your main destination, you are allowed to visit Italy as well, unless otherwise is explicitly stated on the visa (which does not normally happen).

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=GR&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IT&selDest=Italy&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> **Italy**: Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a valid D visa
>   **issued by Greece** for a maximum stay of 90 days

So yes, you can visit Italy for 3 weeks.

Comment: I emailed the Italian embassy in London recently and this is their reply: "You are holding a National Greek Visa, therefore your first port of Entry must be Greece. If before to go to Greece you want to travel to Italy you must apply for a Schengen Tourist Visa.

You will be free to move in other Schengen Countries  after you entered in Greece and applied for a Greek Residence permit." 

Comment: @Leira OK, I called the border police at Rome-Fiumicino Airport and they said as long as your D visa is valid, you're fine. The Timatic database says the same thing, so if check-in staff tries to deny you boarding, ask them to check Timatic, entering Greece as the residence country. It will either a residence Permit **or** D visa is required

Comment: @Coke how do you query the Timatic?

Comment: @Phil https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=GR&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IT&selDest=Italy&selTrans=Use+ctrl-key+to+select+or+deselect+transit+point%28s%29+above&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX

Comment: @Leira If this answer satifies yiu, please upvote it and accept it by pressing the button below the down arrow

Comment: @Leira who did you speak to at the Italian embassy? Whoever it was appears not to know what he or she is talking about.

Comment: "Main destination" is not particularly relevant here since the visa in question is a D visa.

Comment: @Coke thanks for the link but how can we go around querying ourselves? This looks like the result for this particular trip only. Thanks again!

Comment: UPDATE: I arrived in Milan Bergamo today and passed through security without any problem. They didn't look for any document aside from my visa. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Coke i tried upvoting, but i have low reputation (<15) so it says that my upvote won't show. I'm sorry.

Comment: @phoog i emailed the Italian visa office in London because i lived in and got my Greek visa from UK that time . I used this email address: visti.londra@esteri.it.