# Do I need a Schengen visa from Jamaica?

Tags: schengen

Travelling from Jamaica to Miami, then Paris, final destination is Germany. No stopovers, just waiting at the airport in Paris. Do I need a Schengen visa?

Comment: Your nationality would determine whether you need a visa(s); please add that to your question (by using the word ***edit***).

Answer (score 3):

Germany is in Schengen just like France, so the same visa would work.

When entering Schengen you (generally) go through immigration at the first port in Schengen, and travel on mostly like it's a domestic trip. So it's not just waiting at the airport in Paris.

You might also want to read [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa) (the answer is no, but there's more information there)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, both Germany and France are Schengen member states. As your main country appears to be Germany, you will need a Schengen visa issued by your nearest German consulate. The fact that you are entering via France doesn't matter.

You only need a single-entry visa; this allows you to travel around all 26 Schengen member countries as much as you wish (for 90 days). However, when you leave the Schengen area, your visa is automatically cancelled.

Comment: The part about 90 days is not correct. The number of days is stated on the visa and in most cases it is much less than 90.